# how to convert TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE to TIMESTAMP but keeping local time in SQL

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I wonder how such conversion can be done in SQL, e.g.

`2020-07-03 19:47:51.494 America/Los_Angeles` => `2020-07-03 19:47:51.494`

Note the input data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` and the output type is `TIMESTAMP`.

In particular, I'm using prestosql from https://prestosql.io/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . a brute force way is to convert to a string and then back to a timestamp:

```
date_parse(format_datetime(datecol, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

Note that this changes the meaning of the value in the column.  A timestamp with timezone is really a UTC value that is offset *for display purposes*.  I don't recommend doing this in general.  But I have had to do similar operations when local times were moved into "timestamp with timezone" values in a database -- but in the wrong timezone.

Comment: I was doing something similar, also with microseconds. but it feels kind of awkward. So wondering if ther Is a better way, seems not then

Answer (score 2):

Per SQL standard, `CAST` should do that.
In Presto, under default settings, it does not so today.
This is tracked by https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/37

However, you can unlock the SQL standard behavior with a session toggle

```
presto> SET SESSION legacy_timestamp = false;
SET SESSION

presto> SELECT CAST(TIMESTAMP '2020-07-03 19:47:51.494 America/Los_Angeles' AS timestamp);
          _col0
-------------------------
 2020-07-03 19:47:51.494
```

Comment: is there a recommended way apply such behavior behind a view?

Comment: Do you think it would be a good idea to write a presto UDF for such function?

Comment: If you have new UDF ideas, please open a [new issue in Presto project](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

I use the following:

```
from_iso8601_timestamp(substr(to_iso8601(timestamp_with_tz), 1, 19)) as local_timestamp
```

Note that you might need to adjust the `length` parameter in `substr` if you need to keep milliseconds too. When using `19`, it trunks to seconds.